# Spark throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when parallelizing list

Tags: java, arrays, list, apache-spark, indexoutofboundsexception

I've tried to create a Spark implementation of QuickSort to test against a serial implementation. I've got the serial implementation working, but the parallel implementation throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when attempting to parallelize a List of Integers.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10582
at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.accept(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:563)
at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.access$200(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:338)
at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:103)
at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(CachingParanamer.java:90)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.getCtorParams(BeanIntrospector.scala:44)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.findConstructorParam$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$19(BeanIntrospector.scala:176)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:194)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:194)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14(BeanIntrospector.scala:170)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:351)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$._descriptorFor(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:22)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.fieldName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:30)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.findImplicitPropertyName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:78)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:467)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:351)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:283)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:169)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueMethod(BasicBeanDescription.java:223)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:348)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:153)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1203)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:481)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:679)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:107)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3559)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope.toJson(RDDOperationScope.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:699)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:716)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.parallelize(JavaSparkContext.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.parallelize(JavaSparkContext.scala:146)
at Sorter.parallelSort(Sorter.java:83)
at Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

The following is the method in Sorter that throws the exception.

```
private final List<T> unsorted;
private final String master;

...

public List<T> parallelSort() {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("QuickSort").setMaster(master);
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<T> data = sc.parallelize(unsorted);
    ...
}
```

Which is called by the following code from Main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    Sorter<Integer> sorter = new Sorter<>(ints, "local[*]");
    List<Integer> serialSorted = sorter.serialSort();
    List<Integer> parallelSorted = sorter.parallelSort();

    ...
}
```

In case this isn't enough context, the full code I'm using is available on [Github](https://github.com/JellyMyst/QuickSort).

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong to get this exception and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Upgrade your paranamer to 2.8, which is due to your jdk version 1.8

According to [paranamer](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer)

> Release 2.8 - Aug 26 2015 - JDK 8 compatibility improvements, and removal of Codehaus dependencies in build

So in the pom.xml add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Downgrading from spark 2.4.5 to 2.4.0 I encountered this issue.  This fixed it.

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you for quick solution

Answer (score 0):

possibly related to this issue

https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

You have used `spark-core_2.12`. Try using `spark-core_2.11`, it worked for me.

> `<dependency>
>      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
>      <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
>      <version>LATEST</version>
>   </dependency>`